# Selenium 3.7.1 gson dependency throwing a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, selenium, gson, selenium-chromedriver

OS:
Windows 10

Selenium Version: 
3.7.1 (JAVA)

Browser:
Chrome 62.0.3 (64bit)
Chrome driver 2.33.0

After upgrading to Selenium 3.7.1 and chrome driver 2.33.0 my tests are failing due to a Class not found exception on the gson jar. I can see the jar in my maven dependencies. I can get around this issue from inside my eclipse environment by adding the gson as an external jar but this limits me to only running from the IDE.

Has anyone else seen this issue or can anyone see where I'm gone wrong? As gson is included as a dependency of selenium I presume I shouldn't have to add the dependency to my pom. Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Regards
Donagh

Console output

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class Reg_Editor.EditFunctionality
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:31)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:410)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:323)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:191)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:99)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:85)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:42)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:250)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:220)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:169)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_10$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_10.java:28)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_10.java:61)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:616)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:185)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:131)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1383)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1363)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1217)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonParseException
    at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.constructMessage(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.<init>(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:29)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at Util.EMDriverSingleton.setLocalDriver(EMDriverSingleton.java:81)
    at Util.EMDriverSingleton.getDriver(EMDriverSingleton.java:46)
    at Util.Supertest.<init>(Supertest.java:82)
    at Reg_Editor.EditFunctionality.<init>(EditFunctionality.java:16)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 43 more
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ExpertModels</groupId>
    <artifactId>Expert_Models</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <browser>${browser}</browser>
                    <deployment>${deployment}</deployment>
                    <seleniumGrid>${seleniumGrid}</seleniumGrid>
                    <threadCount>0</threadCount>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testNG XML Files\${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Expert_Models</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!--Surefire Reporting POM Dependency -->

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>



    <!--Selenium Dependency -->

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--EXTENT REPORTS DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUNIT DEPENDENCY -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--TESTNG DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--JXL DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Chrome Driver for Maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.33.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--IE Edge Driver for Maven -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId> 
            <version>2.53.0</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- IE Driver for Maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: IMO, the error is cropping up from  mixed dependencies as you have `testng` and `junit` both the dependencies.

Comment: I removed the junit dependency below from the pom but it still throws the same error  

 <!--JUNIT DEPENDENCY -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and see if you have 2 versions of gson. Or you can try to explicitly specify dependency on gson and see if it helps. Also your dependencies might be a bit inconsistent (it depends on the use, but worth checking if it's indeed correct): usually all test dependencies have `<scope>test</scope>`, while you only have that scope on one dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from POM.xml

```
  <!--Chrome Driver for Maven -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--IE Edge Driver for Maven -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId> 
        <version>2.53.0</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- IE Driver for Maven -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

These drivers are transitive dependencies of `selenium-java`, so there are automatically resolved by Maven and there is no need to declare them in `pom.xml`.
If you declare them in th POM.XML, this causes versions conflict of these libraries. Mavens pick a version declared in the POM and ignores the nevest version.

---

If you are using eclipse, you can observe this on `dependency hierarch tab`, it looks like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the info all. I have removed my driver dependencies from the POM and checked the Dependency Hierarchy conflicts exist between the transitive web drivers gson 2.8.2 and the selenium gson 2.8.2 but this resolves. either way, both versions are the same I'm still getting the same error

Comment: All my conflicts are marked as compile and none of the selenium transitive dependencies are replaced by other versions

Comment: If I role back the Selenium version to 3.5.1 my tests run fine